# Google chrome suddenly started opening bootstrap time and date picker automatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-datetimepicker, bootstrap-material-design

in my website, I had added `bootstrapMaterialDatePicker` for picking the date from calendar. Popup need to be opened once clicked on `input` field. It was working fine even few moments ago. But suddenly it has started opening the popup instantly after the page load without clicking on that specific `input` field in chrome browser. But all the other browsers it is working fine.

This is how my html field code is.

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="form-control text-left js-calendar-future" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /](19|20)\d\d" required="">
```

And this is how I had initialized the `bootstrapMaterialDatePicker` library

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $('.js-calendar-future').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    weekStart: 0, 
    time: false,
    minDate: new Date(),
    format: 'MM/DD/Y',
    triggerEvent: 'click',
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally after doing lost of research I found the solution. Just I had to remove `triggerEvent: 'click',` attribute.
So this is my code which worked.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.js-calendar-future').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
   weekStart: 0, 
   time: false,
   minDate: new Date(),
    format: 'MM/DD/Y',
   triggerEvent: 'click',
 });
});
```